# Bash User input taken and run it as showsing it output to terminal

Tags: bash

Im a newbie in bash, how can i make a script where the user will give code like `expr 1 + 1` and the bash script will take the input and make it run like a code the output will also be shown in the terminal

like

```
echo "give your expresiion"
read response 
run $response 
echo return run output
```

Comment: `eval "$response"` -- note the quotes, they're important (simple code can appear to work without them, but complex code can fail in surprising ways)

Comment: See also [BashFAQ #48 - *Eval command and security issues*](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/048) (explaining why `eval` is generally viewed as a Bad Idea); and [BashFAQ #50 - *I'm trying to put a command in a variable, but all the complex cases always fail!*](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050) (explaining why the things people naively try to use instead of `eval` don't work)

Comment: BTW, expr isn't good form in modern code -- it's an artifact of back when shells didn't support built-in math. `echo $(( 1 + 1 ))` has been standardized since the early 1990s; there's almost never a good reason to use expr these days.